# Hex-Rays decompiler stuck on function

Tags: ida, hexrays

I'm working on a Linux x86_64 ELF binary using IDA 6.6.

When I run the Hex-Rays Decompiler on a function (by pressing F5) it always shows me the pseudocode for the `_init_proc` function, no matter what I run it on. It's stuck on that function and won't show me anything else in the pseudocode view. No errors are displayed or printed to the log.

If I produce the C file (Ctrl+F5) the full pseudocode is generated, so it's just an interface issue.

This is driving me mad. Things I've tried:

- Restarting IDA
- Recreating the database
- Deleting all decompiler information for `_init_proc`
- Deleting all decompiler information for the function I'm trying to decompile

Has anyone encountered this behaviour before? Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried reporting this problem to support@hex-rays.com?

Comment: @JasonGeffner I was about to report it, then I solved it myself shortly after asking this question. Should have answered immediately but it was 3AM ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reset IDA configuration

I eventually solved this issue by completely erasing IDA's configuration. I'm on Windows, so I removed the `HKCU\Software\Hex-Rays` key. On Linux you should probably try removing `~/.idapro/ida.reg`.